# Por que no me funciona este RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

pues, estoy como 3 horas intentando que funcione, buscando el error, pero no lo capto... me pueden ayudar es la primera vez que uso el RecyclerView

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        ArrayList<ItemCardViewRV> itemCardViewRVS = new ArrayList<>();
        itemCardViewRVS.add(new ItemCardViewRV("nose", "desc", 55, 5));
        itemCardViewRVS.add(new ItemCardViewRV("nose 2", "desc", 85, 5));

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_cards);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new AdapterRecycleViewCardCake(itemCardViewRVS);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

el AdapterRecycleViewCardCake

```
public class AdapterRecycleViewCardCake extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecycleViewCardCake.ExampleHolderCardCake> {

    private ArrayList<ItemCardViewRV> itemCardViewRVS_list;

    public static class ExampleHolderCardCake extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView mTextView_title;
        public TextView mTextView_desc;

        public TextView mTextView_price;

        public ExampleHolderCardCake(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTextView_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_card_name);
            mTextView_desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_card_desc);
            mTextView_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_card_price);
        }
    }

    public AdapterRecycleViewCardCake(ArrayList<ItemCardViewRV> itemCardViewRVS_v){
        itemCardViewRVS_list = itemCardViewRVS_v;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleHolderCardCake onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_cardview_cakes, parent, false);

        ExampleHolderCardCake everReturn = new ExampleHolderCardCake(v);
        return everReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleHolderCardCake holder, int position) {
        ItemCardViewRV currentItem = itemCardViewRVS_list.get(position);

        holder.mTextView_title.setText(currentItem.getTextView_title());
        holder.mTextView_desc.setText(currentItem.getTextView_desc());
        holder.mTextView_price.setText(currentItem.getPrice());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemCardViewRVS_list.size();
    }
}
```

y el ItemCardViewRV

```
public class ItemCardViewRV {

    private String textView_title;
    private String textView_desc;
    private int price;
    private int starts;

    public  ItemCardViewRV(String nameCake, String description, int price_cost, int start_set){
        textView_title = nameCake;
        textView_desc = description;
        price = price_cost;
        starts = start_set;
    }

    public String getTextView_title() {
        return textView_title;
    }

    public String getTextView_desc() {
        return textView_desc;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getStarts() {
        return starts;
    }
}
```

Bueno, no se que puedo hacer, asique agradeceria su ayuda. gracias.
He estado revisando, pero aún todavia siguo, pero pienso que tal vez sea por falta de variable o un error de id, pero nada, es como si estuviera perfectamente bien...

```
android:layout_margin="3dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cake_001"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:background="@drawable/background_card_price"
            android:paddingStart="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_card_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="$0002"
                android:textColor="#fff"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_card_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TITLE"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/color_card_title"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_card_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description of this"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center|end"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textView_card_price_1"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textView_card_price_2"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textView_card_price_3"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textView_card_price_4"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_star_black_24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/textView_card_price_5"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_star_half_black_24dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ORDENAR"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_ordenar"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Diganme, que creen que pueda ser el problema? es urgente porfavor gracias.

El xml principal:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_search"

            />

        <!--androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycleview_cards_cakes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            /-->

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_cards"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Que mensaje te muestra en el Logcat?

Comment: Si no usas el LogCat puedes tardar días tratando de solucionar un problema en lugar de algunos segundo, te recomiendo usarlo, saludos.

Comment: Cual es el problema que tienes?